# AttributeError : module "tensorflow"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to ask about my specific problem.
When i run this code retrain.py from github

i got this kind of error as below:

```
 File "retrain.py", line 1325, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you using? in tf 2.0, there seems no tf.app but you can try  tf.compat.v1.app.run.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: no I upgrade my TensorFlow version

Answer (score 0):

There may be several possible problems... I would check the following two in the first place:

**1) problems tensorflow version**: if you are using TensorFlow 2.0 you need to replace `tf.app.flags` with `tf.compat.v1.flags` ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/flags ).

**2) probelms with tensorflow installation**. For example, you can try: `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)` and see if you have the same error. In such a case you can try to install TensorFlow again. Remember that if you had installed it in a virtual environment, then you would have to activate it before using python (e.g. in the terminal use: `>>> source venv/bin/activate`).